# Install TCP Wrappers in Slackware 14.2

Tags: software-installation, package-management, slackware

How to install TCP Wrappers using the appropriate package manager? When I run pkgtool, I can see in the list that tcp_wrappers is included `tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1`. I want to install it.

I tried the command below, with no luck.

```
 installpkg tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
```

Whenever I run the command above, it says

```
 Cannot install, file not found.
```

So I navigated to `/var/log/packages`, where the list of Slackware packages are listed and I found the `tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1` file. So what I did is:

```
mv tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1 tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
installpkg tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
```

The prompt message is :

```
Verifying package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
gzip : stdin : not in gzip format
Installing package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz:
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
WARNING: Package has not been created with 'makepkg'
Package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz installed.
```

After, I verified whether the tcp_wrappers is already installed using the commands below, with no luck.

```
rpm -q tcp_wrappers
rpm -q tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1
rpm -q tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
```

It just say:

```
package tcp_wrappers is not installed 
package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1 is not installed
package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz is not installed
```

What shall I do?

Comment: it seems from `gzip : stdin : not in gzip format` that the tgz file you have is not in the correct format; try download it again?